# Generating code from other sources to be used alongside Dagger

Tags: android, code-generation, dagger-2

In my application I am aiming to use a **Gradle plugin (jsonSchema2Pojo)** to generate the model classes, and I'm also using **Dagger2**. If I generate the model classes separately and then include them in the project, things work out fine. But if I try to generate both at the same time, (what I think is happening is that) **Dagger** tries to run before the **jsonSchema2Pojo** task and it doesn't finish properly because it doesn't find the model classes. Because it doesn't finish properly, it prevents the model classes from being generated and back to square one.

My idea was to make the **Dagger** generation tasks depend on the **jsonSchema2Pojo**, but the thing is that I have no clue what these tasks are.

What is the procedure to follow with this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/269. `2.1-SNAPSHOT` should work for you.

Comment: Not really, doesn't make a difference. Note that my Dagger~ class is indeed generated (unlike that of the issue), but the corresponding module provides an instance of class A, and class A uses the to-be-generated model classes, which don't exist yet.

Comment: Can you try to make a sample project which exhibits this, and then post an issue on Github linking to the repo/code?

Comment: https://github.com/stoyicker/boats-xkcd/tree/master/data In model you can find the jsonSchema2Pojo definition of the class (DataEntity). Then in src/.../net/ you'll find classes like XkcdClient, which import the conflicting DataEntity class. The version in master is working because I've copied the generated class into src and disabled the plugin, but I'll make a new branch illustrating the exact case.